# Handling # uri fragments as regular requests

Tags: htaccess, javascript, mod-rewrite, apache2, html5

So I have a one-page website with multiple sections and IDs. Right now, in the nav, I have it going to #about to jump them down to a section with ID=about

But I want the user to be able to go to mysite.com/#about but without the #. So if the user goes to mysite.com/about, it will jump them down to the about section on the same domain.

How can I accomplish this? I imagine it's a dot htaccess modification with some javascript?

I've Googled all over for a solution but to no avail.

Comment: I would discourage that, the # is understood as navigating to a section of the page, a example.com/about is understood as being a different page. Everybody who does not understand what you are trying to do, (which would be everybody you have not told), would think your site was broken and the about page didn't actually exist because the browser is navigating, (you would need to create the code), to the about section of the main page. Those who would not understand would include screen readers and search engines.

Comment: You would need to use the NE flag to (no escape) the special character ... rageagainstshell.com/2018/10/… ... but again others would see your site as broken.

Comment: https://rageagainstshell.com/2018/10/special-characters-in-url-rewrite-with-mod_rewrite/

Comment: You would only need the `NE` flag if you are issuing an external redirect to the `#fragid`. You could instead treat the one-page website as a front-controller (rewriting the request) and let JS read the URL and do the necessary, as mentioned in [my answer](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/140982/1243). @Wayne

Comment: @MrWhite yes I didn't consider that when I commented - I tunnel visioned to the special character

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the file that renders your "one-page" site is `index.html` and your "pages" are `/about`, `/contact` and `/help` that correspond to elements with `id`s of the same name (less the slash prefix).

Your root `.htaccess` code would be something like the following, using mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(about|contact|help)$ index.html [L]
```

The above rewrites requests for the 3 URLs stated to `index.html`. So, those 3 URLs get the same HTTP response.

Then, JavaScript on the page would be something like:

```
// Get the URL-path, less the slash prefix
const id = location.pathname.substring(1);

// Get the HTML "page" element whose ID is passed in the URL.
const element = document.getElementById(id);
if (element) {
    element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

Note that the `id` could be *empty* or `index.html`. (*Aside:* You could redirect from `/index.html` to `/` in `.htaccess`.)

Although, as mentioned in comments, this might have accessibility issues over using the standard fragment identifier. And `/#about` and `/about` will return the same response - the first being handled by the browser and the second by JavaScript.

Reference:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: You'd also have issues with duplicated content on those pages, seeing as you're serving the same content on each URL just jumping to different sections. A `cannonical` would help, but would probably result in search engines only indexing the homepage.